# Plugin 'kotlin-parcelize' not found

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Google is recommending users to migrate from `kotlin-android-extensions` to `kotlin-parcelize`.

However, Gradle sync fails with the following error:

```
Plugin [id: 'kotlin-parcelize'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (not a core plugin, please see https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/standard_plugins.html for available core plugins)
- Plugin Repositories (plugin dependency must include a version number for this source)
```

Where is the plugin located?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`kotlin-parcelize` ships with Kotlin Plugin `1.4.20`
([Release Announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/11/kotlin-1-4-20-released/): Deprecation of Kotlin Android Extensions)

You need to upgrade your Kotlin versions and run Gradle sync again.

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20"
}
```

Comment: nice! updating that classpath on my project's build.gradle solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 35):

**1**, update your AndroidStudio kotlin version
From menu, select `Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates` -> choose a kotlin version -> install -> **and restart** AS

**2**, update your dependencies classpath with the new kotlin version then sync project (like Brown Smith answer)

**3**
builld.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

MyObject.kt

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
class MyObject(val name: String, val age: Int) : Parcelable {

}
```

Comment: Any idea why the following import still works even after removing the extensions plugin ?
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

Comment: not sure but maybe some other third party library that your application is using may include it @KaranSharma

Answer (score 8):

This is the latest `september 2021` implementation :

If you're using `'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.20'` or above , and you fail to find the parcelize tag , you can add it using the plugins DSL in the `settings.gradle` :

```
plugins {  
 id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize" version "1.6.0-M1" 
}
```

and then call it in your app `build.gradle` like this :

```
plugins { 
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your module level build.gradle file add,

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

In your project level build.gradle file add,

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
    
    }
}
```

Here '1.4.32' is the Kotlin package version.
You will now be able to find the `Parcelize` package. Also while importing make sure to import:

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

package.

Comment: Also remove plugin `kotlin-android-extensions` if was added, because they are incompatible together. But if you use synthetic, it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

in `bulid.gradle` (`Project:*appname*`) add:

```
buildscript {
    
    dependencies {
        ...
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}
```

and in `bulid.gradle` (`Module:*appname*`) add:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize'
}
```

If it didn't work for you check this link (if there's a new update): https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize

Answer (score 2):

**1.** `Make sure Gradle should be on Online mode`

[image]

**2.** `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'`

**3.** `need to upgrade your Kotlin versions 1.4.20 or above and run Gradle sync again.`

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in newest android studio in **Nov 2021:**

in `setting.gradle` add this line:

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize") version "1.6.0-M1"
```

and in `build.gradle` of module:

```
 id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.parcelize")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: kotlin-android-extensions is being deptecared, better to use kotlin-parcelize. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42121

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is

```
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" 
plugins {
   ...
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```