# Migrate to the new kotlin-parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

Can anyone please explain how to migrate to the [new](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/11/the-future-of-kotlin-android-extensions.html) `kotlin-parcelize`?

I tried:

1. Replace `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` with `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'` in app build.gradle
2. Replace `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` with `import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize`

The latter one leads to

```
Class 'ParcelZonedDateTime' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun describeContents(): Int defined in android.os.Parcelable
```

on e.g. this code:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime

@Keep
@Parcelize
data class ParcelZonedDateTime(var value: ZonedDateTime?) :Parcelable {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```

So, how to migrate to the new `kotlin-parcelize`?

**Update:**

Based on comments: Yes, I am on Kotlin 1.4.20 (which is newer than 1.4.20-M2).Kyzer is right that the error in the IDE (*is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun describeContents()*) can and has to be ignored. Yet I have an issue where I use Generics:

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

sealed class MyDialogEvent {
    @Parcelize
    data class Confirmed<T: Parcelable>(val identity: String, val data: T) : Parcelable
}
```

The generated code for this is

```
@kotlin.Metadata(mv = {1, 4, 1}, bv = {1, 0, 3}, k = 3)
public static final class Creator implements android.os.Parcelable.Creator<com.example.stackoverflow.MyDialogEvent.Confirmed> {
    
    public Creator() {
        super();
    }
    
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @java.lang.Override()
    public final com.example.stackoverflow.MyDialogEvent.Confirmed<T>[] newArray(int size) {
        return null;
    }
    
    @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    @java.lang.Override()
    public final com.example.stackoverflow.MyDialogEvent.Confirmed<T> createFromParcel(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
    android.os.Parcel in) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and during compilation I get this error for it (line numbers won't match the sample code, but you can easily identify the matching lines by comparing the method names):

```
MyDialogEvent.java:167: error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
            public final com.example.stackoverflow.MyDialogEvent.Confirmed<T>[] newArray(int size) {
                                                                                       
MyDialogEvent.java:173: error: non-static type variable T cannot be referenced from a static context
            public final com.example.stackoverflow.MyDialogEvent.Confirmed<T> createFromParcel(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Comment: Did you also update kotlin to 1.4.20?

Comment: note this plugin is only available starting from version 1.4.20-M2

Comment: What do you mean leads to? If you have updated to 1.4.20. For me, the IDE shows the error but the project builds fine.

Comment: @KyzerSoze Good hint, thanks for that. Now I have a new issue though. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: @SarahKhan: Thanks, I am on 1.4.20. Would be glad if you could also check my update.

Comment: @BenP. Yes, I am on 1.4.20. Would be glad if you could also check my update.

Comment: @KyzerSoze: It's an reduced example. There are further classes in the sealed class. One can use sealed classes as some kind of enum of classes. Actually that worked fine until the (attempted) migration to `kotlinx.parcelize`.

Comment: Sorry do not have info on that, but I'm positive generics won't work with the annotation irrespective of package or sealed class due to the fact that methods in the static context in the generated class do not know what generic type T is

Comment: Looks like the Parcelize generics error is introduced by Kotlin 1.4.20 itself, not the plugin migration. I still get the same error if you roll back to `kotlin-android-extensions` and keep Kotlin 1.4.20.

Comment: I'm facing same issue in kotlin 1.4.21 so I roll back my code in to 1.4.10 that's working fine

Comment: I have same issue in my project too. I tried 1.4.21 version but the error is still there. Is anybody find solution for this? This is really annoying.

Comment: I didn't dig further into this, but added a bounty now. Hopefully someone has an answer to this. Or maybe it's a bug and a fix needed? ):

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf regarding your issue with Generics I suggest you post a question on youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I need a fix for this, i am suffering from the same error :(

Comment: Still an issue with Kotlin 1.4.30

Comment: For an updated guide that includes using custom @TypeParcelers, see this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71354186/2857200

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's a bug in kapt and it's reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42652). Actually the java code you posted is a stub class which generated by kapt to run annotation processors on it (as you can see, there is no real implementation, just the structure and annotations). So as a workaround you can move the code with `@Parcelize` annotations to a separate module where you don't have kapt enabled. `kotlin-parcelize` itself does not use annotation processors to generate code, it uses a compiler plugin to emit the IR directly I believe.

**Update: the issue is fixed in kotlin 1.5**

Comment: How wold we go about moving the code into a separate module? Would this mean the second module would have a separate Gradle file?

Answer (score 4):

This is work for me, please check the order of lines carefully

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'    
   }
```

Comment: I have written an article on how to use custom @TypeParcelers here:

https://medium.com/@chrisathanas/how-to-use-parcels-on-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-e29590816624

Answer (score 1):

After further checking, I think `Parcelable` generic type with Parcel constructing fails to compile because `T class` can not be determined generically based from this [reference](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize#types).

[image]

Perhaps an enum could be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Kotlin version 1.4.10:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10"
```

but in my module, only apply

```
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

and it work for me.

There is all my plugins apply in my module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Comment: And you use a `kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` implementation. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981310/plugin-kotlin-parcelize-not-found.

Comment: Check out this article to be able to use a @TypeParceler for non-primitive classes.
https://medium.com/@chrisathanas/how-to-use-parcels-on-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-kmm-e29590816624

Answer (score -1):

Answer for original question:

If you see this error in Android Studio:

```
Class 'ClassName' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun describeContents(): Int defined in android.os.Parcelable
```

Make sure that you have updated both Kotlin dependency and Android Studio Kotlin plugin to 1.4.20 or later.
[image]
After updating the plugin make sure to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart. That worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it didn't work for me. I'm targeting 1.4.30 in both - project and as AS plugin, AS ver. 4.1.2. After invalidating caches, still the same issue.

Answer (score -4):

change this line:
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
to:
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

Comment: But that's deprecated! Which was the whole point of the migration