# Unresolved `kotlin-parcelize`

Tags: android, kotlin

I have multi module app and added plugin `id 'kotlin-parcelize` into app module. But it still shows `Unresolved reference`. Kotlin version is 1.5.10.

I know there are similar [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981310/plugin-kotlin-parcelize-not-found) and [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925126/how-to-use-parcelize-now-that-kotlin-android-extensions-is-being-deprecated) but I tried everything described there but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `kotlin-parcelize` depends on `kotlin-android` and ordering of the plugins matters. So it should be like here:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

Comment: If I made these change in Windows 10, with andrid studio, I start to get an error with the cocopods plugin, which until the added, works fine